# Intellij not detecting appropriate Java version in Tycho/Maven build

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, tycho

I'm trying to migrate a Tycho/Maven project from Eclipse PDE to Intellij and i'm having trouble getting Intellij to use the appropriate java source versions. In particular, my `MANIFEST.MF` has `Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.7`, and my `tycho-compiler-plugin` has `configuration -> [source|target]` both equal to `1.7`. The modules are imported into Intellij as maven projects with an OSGI facet.

Whenever I reimport the poms for the modules, it sets the language-level in the module to 1.5, which I understand to be the default. Where does Intellij pick op the project language level for these projects such that I can get it to detect the one I'd like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got same problem. Solved with adding to pom.xml:

```
  <properties>
     <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
     <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>
```